# Problems when start my service

Tags: bash, perl, service, centos, systemd

Centos 7

The problem is this: If I write in the console:

```
/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int start
```

Everything is OK, the service is started. If you create a service file and do this:

```
systemctl start realplexor
```

that service falls into the error (in this case does not write or where for some reason) and do not create PID file. Tell me, because of what it can be? Inside dklab_realplexor.int run perl script with parameters.

```
cd $CWD && $BIN $CONF -p $PIDFILE 2>&1 | logger -p `eval" echo $LOGPRI "` -t `eval" echo $LOGTAG "` &
```

Full service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=realplexor

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dklab_realplexor_dklab_realplexor.conf.pid
WorkingDirectory=/opt/dklab_realplexor

User=root
Group=root

Environment=RACK_ENV=production

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStart=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int start
ExecStop=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int stop
ExecReload=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int reload
TimeoutSec=5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Tell me, please, in what side to dig?

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces in the paths of the systemd service file?

Comment: @xxfelixxx, I'm sorry, I have corrected the block in the request. The file does not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script uses environment variables which are not defined in your service file.
To see list available environment variables add to your script (dklab_realplexor.int):

```
env | sort
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
If I understand correctly you need to insert the line:
`cd $CWD && $BIN $CONF -p $PIDFILE 2>&1 | logger -p \`eval" echo $LOGPRI "\` -t \`eval" echo $LOGTAG "\` &`
If it is so - it does not work :(

Comment: I mean to add command "env|sort" as a first line in your script. Now try to execute script directly and using "systemctl". Check the differences in output. I suppose your env variables CWD, BIN, CONF are not defined when "systemctl" is running, so you should define them or you can't use them.

Comment: I tried this:
`perl /opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.pl /etc/dklab_realplexor.conf -p /var/run/dklab_realplexor_dklab_realplexor.conf.pid 2>&1 &` ie remove variables and specify the path and the error persists.